# I'm getting errors on output.writeObject(new Boolean(true)); and also on Chat_ServerThread chatClient = new Chat_ServerThread(...)

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Chat_Server extends JFrame
{   

// total number of clients that can be logged on to the message service
final int NO_OF_CLIENTS = 4; 
// this ArrayList will store the client threads
ArrayList<Chat_ServerThread> chatClients = new ArrayList<Chat_ServerThread>();
// arrays containing valid names and passwords
String[] names = {"Adam Smith", "Bill Allen", "Cathy Clark", "Davina Doe"};
String[] passwords = {"LuQezz169", "amG4tyz", "Dw1wU9wy", "Fre195Ufm"};
// array containing valid chat tags
String [] chattag = {"Arken", "Ben", "DarkLark", "Free", "group"};
// this array indicates whether a client is currently logged on
boolean loggedOn[] = new boolean[NO_OF_CLIENTS];

// GUI components
JTextArea outputArea;

//Other Declartations
ServerSocket serverSocket;
DataInputStream serverInputStream;
DataOutputStream serverOutputStream; 


public Chat_Server()
{   super("Chat_Server");
    addWindowListener
    (   new WindowAdapter()
        {   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {   System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    );

    try
    {   // gets a serversocket and binds to port 6000
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6000);

    }
    catch(IOException e) // thrown by ServerSocket
    {   System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // create and add GUI components
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    // add text output area
    outputArea = new JTextArea(17,30);
    outputArea.setEditable(false);
    outputArea.setLineWrap(true);
    outputArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    c.add(outputArea);
    c.add(new JScrollPane(outputArea));
    setSize(360,310);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}

void getClients()
{   // add message to server output area
    addOutput("Server is up and waiting for a connection...");
    int userCount = 0;
    while(userCount < NO_OF_CLIENTS)
    {   try
        {   /* client has attempted to get a connection to server,
               create a socket to communicate with this client */
        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

            // get input & output streams
        ObjectInputStream serverInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream serverOutputStrean = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

            // add message to server output area
            addOutput("Server is up and waiting for a connection...");
            // read encrypted username from input stream & decrypt
            EncryptedMessage uname = (EncryptedMessage)serverInputStream.readObject();
            uname.decrypt();
            // read encrypted password from input stream & decrypt
            EncryptedMessage pword = (EncryptedMessage)serverInputStream.readObject();
            pword.decrypt();

            // add messages to server output area
            addOutput("\nLogin Details Received\n----------------------------------------");
            addOutput("encrypted username : " + uname.getMessage());
            addOutput("encrypted password : " + pword.getMessage());

            boolean valid = false;
            int pos = Arrays.binarySearch(names, uname);
            if(pos >= 0)
            {   if(passwords[pos].equals(pword) && !loggedOn[pos])
                {   addOutput("Login details received from client " + (userCount+1) + ", " + uname + " are valid");
                    addOutput("Client " + uname + " is known as " + chattag[pos]);
                    valid = true;
                    loggedOn[pos] = true;
                    // send Boolean value  true to client
                    output.writeObject(new Boolean(true));
```

This returns an error on output. saying that it cannot be resolved

```
                    // add this new thread to the array list
                    Chat_ServerThread chatClient = new Chat_ServerThread (serverInputStream, serverOutputStream, names[pos], chattag[pos]);
```

This returns an error within the Chatserver thread. I'm also getting errors on output.writeobject. I'm not sure why it is doing this hopefully someone will be able to shed some light on things. it says that the constructor is not defined

```
                    chatClients.add(chatClient);

                    // start thread - execution of the thread will begin at method run
                    chatClient.start();

                    userCount++;
                }
            }
            if(!valid)
            {   /* user is not registered therefore write a Boolean value
                   false to the output stream */
                output.writeObject(new Boolean(false));
                addOutput("Login details received from client " + (userCount+1) + ", " + uname + " are invalid");
            }
        }
```

Comment: `output.writeObject` gives an error because you haven't got anything called `output`. In order to explain the error with `Chat_ServerThread`, you'd need to show that class.

Comment: You should always post the *exact* error message. Not a paraphrase, précis, summary, interpretation, ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not created the instance of `output`. Try first initializing it with a constructor for whatever class it is you want `output` to be an instance of.

Regarding the constructor not being defined, check the constructor(s) for the `Chat_ServerThread` class and ensure that the arguments you are passing to the constructor match those which are defined in one of `Chat_ServerThread`'s implemented constructors.

Comment: The Chat_ServerThread isnt a class in itself. where or how would i initialize a constructor of output?

Comment: If Chat_ServerThread isn't a class, then what is it? You are creating an ArrayList of type Chat_ServerThread, so there must be a Class that represents it somewhere. As for a constructor for output, it's not clear what class 'output' is an instance of. Which class are you wanting to make an instance of?